# Visualize KPI with Trend in Quicksight

Tags: analytics, amazon-quicksight

I want to create a KPI Metric in Quicksight that takes the sum of "Views generated" over a custom period of time. The period is entered within parameters and passed to a filter (e.g. Parameter DateFrom: 2021-03-06; Parameter DateTo: 2021-03-10). Besides the sum I also want to show a percentage increase/decrease compared to the period before (2021-03-01 - 2021-03-05).

Example:
I have a table like that:

| Date | Views |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-03-01 | 5 |
| 2021-03-02 | 10 |
| 2021-03-03 | 15 |
| 2021-03-04 | 10 |
| 2021-03-05 | 0 |
| 2021-03-06 | 7 |
| 2021-03-07 | 13 |
| 2021-03-08 | 5 |
| 2021-03-09 | 20 |
| 2021-03-10 | 5 |

Now it should show the sum of the views of the period between 2021-03-06 and 2021-03-10 which is  **50** and compare it with the period before (2021-03-01 - 2021-03-05) which is **40** and show that there was an increase of views by 20% compared with the period before. Smth like that:

[image]

As I'm completely new to AWS Quicksight I haven't figured out a way to achieve that. There is an insight called "period-over-period", which I think does exactly what I need, but I do not get how I can actually use the custom time period. Does anyone have an idea?